# How to call function once on max length of input in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, debugging, maxlength

Here is simple function I want to call confirm when input length = 6 but the issue in this way is that some time it call multiple time same function on max length. I want to call function once only when max length reach.

```
 onOtpChange(event: any) {
    if (event.length == 6) {
      this.authcode = event
      this.confirm();
    }
  }
```

Call function at once on max input length

Comment: Without context it's hard to recommend an approach, but could you simply use a flag? `if (event.length === 6 && methodNotCalled)` (suggest you use strong equality either way)

Comment: @WillAlexander Is methodNotCalled any predefined method?

Comment: No, you have it as a flag in your class, initially set to `false`, and you set it to `true` when the method is first called